# Taylor Polynomial please explain order meaning? (example included)

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

When I am asked to find a Taylor polynomial of order 6th for example, does that mean that my answer HAS to include only powers of x up to 6? I am not sure how to solve the following example.

Ex: Compute T6 of (1+x^2)(e^(-x^3))

Here, I find T6 of e^(-x^3)) and it stops at x^6 but when I multiply it by (1+x^2) , my result includes x^8. Is my answer correct or not? Does that mean I have to compute T4e^(-x^3)? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange! You are right. If zeros appear, you can omit them. So, the series can stop earlier. It would help if you show the series you have calculated.

Comment: OK, now I think I got the point. You can stop at order $6$ AFTER you multiplied with $(1+x^2)$. You are supposed to calculate the taylor series for the product, not only for the e-part. You should get $1+x^2-x^3-x^5+1/2x^6$. Multiplying T4 with $1+x^2$ is not correct, since it gives $(1-x^3)(1+x^2)=1+x^2-x^3-x^5$

Comment: If we calculate $(1-x^3+1/2x^6)(1+x^2)$ and omit the term $1/2x^8$, everything is fine.

Comment: Okay so you are saying  I should show my work including (1/2)*x^8 and then in my final answer I just omit it right?

Comment: Yes, you can stop at $x^6$ because higher powers multiplicated with $1+x^2$ give higher powers, which can be omitted. So, you can do it as you mentioned.